# Entity Framework Two queries with same results, but one is faster

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, entity-framework

I recently experienced a performance problem in Entity Framework querying against SQL Server 2008. I managed to fix the issue, but I don't understand why my fix worked. I'm using a collection of Guids with a .Contains() method to generate an IN clause in SQL. Here's the original code (table names changed to protect the innocent):

```
Guid[] values = filter.Split(',').Select<String, Guid>(d => new Guid(d)).ToArray();


returnValue = returnValue.Where(t => values.Contains(t.WorkItem.Requirement.Project.ProjectId));
```

This query takes ~20 seconds for execution when there are > 150 ProjectID's. By changing the location of the .Contains() I can speed things up dramatically. Here's the refactor:

```
Guid[] values = filter.FilterValue.Split(',').Select<String, Guid>(d => new Guid(d)).ToArray();

var projects = from p in context.DC_DEF_Project
               where values.Contains(p.ProjectId)
               select p;

returnValue = from t in returnValue
              join p in projects on t.DC_DEF_ProjectWorkItem.DC_DEF_ProjectRequirement.ProjectId equals p.ProjectId
              select t;
```

This code takes ~0.125 seconds on the same data set as the above query.

I'm sure there's a sane reason for this, but my curiosity is killing me. What is it?

Comment: what is the sql each code would create? LOok at that and see the differnces and look at the execution plan for each to see why one is slower than the other,

Comment: I also suggest doing a profiling session and compare the actual SQL that is generated by both queries.

Comment: Could you show the declaration and initialization of returnValue? What is its type?

Comment: returnValue is passed into this method as an IQueryable<Task> object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess would be that the first one results in sql with a bunch or ORs evaluated against the foreign key on workitems after all the joins where the second joins mach to projects by it's primary key and evaluates the 150 ids only once then joins that to the other tables.

Comment: Bill For The Win! I profiled the two methods. The slower one has a query with an OR clause for each item in the .Contains, while the faster one uses an IN Clause as I originally expected both to do.

Comment: This pattern shows up a lot in one of my projects where something randomly turns into an OR disaster through EF.  If anyone finds the true trigger/threshold for this I would LOVE to know as well.

Answer (score 0):

I think in the first example, you are bringing the entire dataset over to your app and then doing an in-memory linq query against it.

Comment: Considering they are both IQueryable, why would it swithc to LINQ2Objects?

Comment: It probably wouldn't, but in the first example I dont see where returnValue is set. Perhaps it implements IEnumberable instead?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understood the working of Linq it must have something to do with the deferred execution of the queries.

In your fixed version, you have two Linq expressions that will be evaluated and interpreted **one after the other**, but executed **only once** when you enumerate the results (*if ever*). That neatly **reduces database accesses**.

The first version:

```
returnValue.Where(t => values.Contains(t.WorkItem.Requirement.Project.ProjectId))
```

does **not** do any filtering in the first step. It will do a check if the `ProjectId` of the current table row is contained in `values` for **every row** of the table!